# Authorization and Application Server - no ajax. How to use bearer tokens?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have an authorization server with all my user accounts and I have my application server which has MVC5 controllers, it's own separate database, and views.

I can get the bearer token from my authorization server by using HttpClient:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var result = await client.PostAsync(BuildActionUri("/Token"), new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("userName", userName), 
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
            }));

            string json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            }

            throw new ApiException(result.StatusCode, json);
        }
```

Now how do I store the authorization token so controllers know the user is authorized?

Answer (score 0):

If the two servers share a trusted network, then you could send the auth tokens to the app server via some transport over the trusted network -or- the app server would make a request to the auth service to validate the token. You must make sure, though, that this functionality isn't available via the public network because then anyone could inject trust.

Otherwise, if there is no way to make a trusted connection, there will need to be a shared data source of some type. This could be a database, an in-memory cache, a file system if you had absolutely no other choice.

Regardless, there needs to be a mechanism for sharing tokens and their expiration times between the servers.

Comment: The issue isn't how to get or where to store the token. The issue is how do I get the mvc5 controller to read the token before authorization Attribute.